# The meaning of word "مَّحْفُوظًاۖ" independent of other verses

Tags: quran-translation, arabic-translation

In Quran 21:32 word "مَّحْفُوظًاۖ", what is the correct translation of it, protected or protective not taking other verse in account for translation, only taking this word independent from other verse. I know this Q is been asked but answer are is always in references of other verse. what is meaning of above word independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mahfūz is the maf'ūl form of hafaza.

Hafaza means to protect.

The maf'ūl form indicates the object of an action. So, for a given verb, it would mean "the one that is verbed."

For example, مَغْضُوبِ means "the one that is angered upon" and مَعْلُومَ means "the thing that is known."

Similarly, Mahfūz means "the one that is protected."